# Count need to get for only particular item in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode, T_Master_Item.itemName as Description,
   T_Master_Item.categoryCode as Category, 
   sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) As Qty,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) Good,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Defective 
FROM T_BOE_Stock_Detail 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Master_Item ON T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode = T_Master_Item.itemCode
group by T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode, T_Master_Item.itemName,T_Master_Item.categoryCode
having sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) > 0 
order by T_Master_Item.categoryCode, T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode
```

I am getting output like this:

```
 itemcode   description   category     qty  good   defective
  076-00002  bottom                    2       6     1
```

I want to calculate the count of good and defective only for particular item (I mean which all item code qty > 0, qty calculating like this: ((T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) >0)

My expected output like this:

```
 itemcode   description   category     qty  good   defective
  076-00002  bottom                    2       1      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you `SUM` makes the count on all the rows, not just the ones with Qty > 0

Try this edit:

```
SELECT T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode, T_Master_Item.itemName as Description,
T_Master_Item.categoryCode as Category, 
sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) As Qty,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) Good,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Defective 
FROM T_BOE_Stock_Detail 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Master_Item ON T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode = T_Master_Item.itemCode
WHERE T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty > 0
group by T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode, T_Master_Item.itemName,T_Master_Item.categoryCode
having sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) > 0 
order by T_Master_Item.categoryCode, T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode
```

This way you only get the rows with Qty, and the `SUM` wil not count the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count quantity for good and reserved fields, change the `CASE` statements like this:

```
SELECT ...
sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) As Qty,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' THEN qty ELSE 0 END  ) Good,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) Defective 
FROM T_BOE_Stock_Detail 
..
```

If you want to count the number of rows it will be:

```
SELECT ...
sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) As Qty,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' 
    AND T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty > 0 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Good,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' 
    AND T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty > 0 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Defective 
FROM T_BOE_Stock_Detail 
..
```